# Getting Values of QuerySet in Django

Tags: django, django-queryset

How can I get value of `course_code` in this QuerySet?

```
<QuerySet [{'course_code': 11}]>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
course_qs = <whatever query gave you the queryset>
for course in course_qs:
    print(course['course_code'])
```

Comment: Why am I getting error **TypeError: 'DutyModeOfCalc' object is not subscriptable**

Comment: @user12379095 this is because a queryset return a list, an array. You cannot possibly tell that list to look for index 'course_code', it doesn't exist. You'd have to either loop through it or specify the index in the list, and then for each object you can indicate ['course_code']. It means that this answer is not the correct one

Comment: why does queryset not provide any function to get a list? why should I have to loop through every time I fetch a column for example.

Answer (score 19):

Use this

```
someTable.objects.all()[0]['course_code']
```

or

```
someTable.objects.values_list('course_code', flat = True)
```

Comment: `someTable.objects.values_list('course_code', flat = True)` this returns a queryset.

Comment: ... not a list*

Comment: thank you so much that flat=True saved my life

Answer (score 10):

```
courses = <your query set>
print(courses[0]['course_code'])
```

Answer (score 4):

Now is much easier than before. for instance, you can use:

```
obj = Model.objects.all().first()  # {'course_code': 11}
course_code = obj.course_code      # 11
```

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me:

```
course_qs = <whatever query gave you the queryset>  
list_of_course = list(course_qs)
```

[When QuerySets are evaluated](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/django-2-by/9781788472487/c0d84fbe-ed96-47e5-b185-cf86335da8d6.xhtml)

1. The first time you iterate over them
2. When you slice them, for instance, Post.objects.all()[:3]
3. When you pickle or cache them
4. When you call repr() or len() on them
5. When you explicitly call list() on them
6. When you test them in a statement, such as `bool()`, `or` , `and`, or `if`

Answer (score 2):

Okay this is what i did.

1:

```
items = ItemParent.objects.filter(item_type__contains="something")
# <QuerySet [<Item: iron>]>
```

2:

```
items.values()
# <QuerySet [{'id': 5, 'item_parent_id': 8, 'item_type': 'iron', 'item_article_no': '12336'}]>
```

3:

```
items.values()["id"]
# 5
```

When **QuerySets** is multiple sets:

```
# <QuerySet [{'id': 5, 'item_parent_id': 8, 'item_type': 'iron', 'item_article_no': '12336'},
#            {'id': 6, 'item_parent_id': 9, 'item_type': 'rust', 'item_article_no': '12338'}]>

item_id_one = items.values()[0]["id"]
item_id_two = items.values()[1]["id"]
# etc..
```

Or in my case:

```
for f in items.values()
    item_id = f["id"]
```

Answer (score 1):

> You can try the following which will return a list of values from the
>   queryset.

```
courses = <your query set>
linked_content = []
for content in courses:
    linked_content.append(content)
return linked_content
```

Answer (score 1):

This returns a Query Set: Django 4.0

```
result = User.objects.filter(Q(ip__icontains='count')) #<QuerySet [<User: count>]>
```

This returns the value of count:

```
result.values('count').get()['count']
```

However this is crazy compilcated?! There must and should be a simpler solution...

Model:

```
class User(django.Model):
     count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
>>> course_code = str(table_name.objects.all()[0])
>>> course_code
'11'
```